# Convert $\ddot{y}(t) = \dot{y}(t)-y(t)^2$ with $y(0)=y_0, \dot{y}(0) = y_1$ into a first order IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

We're given the following 2. order IVP

$$\ddot{y}(t) = \dot{y}(t)-y(t)^2$$ with initial values $y(0)=y_0, \dot{y}(0) = y_1$. We're asked to convert it into a first Order IVP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We set $z_0= y(t), z_1 = \dot{y}(t)$

$\begin{bmatrix}
z_0(t)  \\
z_1(t)  
\end{bmatrix}
 : = 
\begin{bmatrix}
y(t)  \\
\dot{y}(t)  
\end{bmatrix}$

Thus $\frac{dz}{dt}(t)= \begin{bmatrix}
z_1(t) \\
z_1(t) - z_0(t)^2 
\end{bmatrix}$ with initial values

$z(t_0=0)= 
\begin{bmatrix}
y_0 \\
y_1 
\end{bmatrix} $